# Correctly Setting Up SSTP VPN On Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, sstp

I'm in the process of setting up a VPN server, and with the environment, it seems that the SSTP VPN would be the best choice for me.  I don't care to buy a certificate, I can sign one myself, though I don't know how to do so.

Are there any good guides out there for signing a certificate for self use and setting it up with a working SSTP VPN system?  I've been trying to set up VPN for about a week now and I've almost given up, this is about to be my last hope.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Alright so I have a self signed certificate joined to IIS so that https works. But now when I'm connecting my client through SSTP VPN, I get an error message that says:

"Error 0x800B0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider."

Any idea what to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machine (client) you are using to connect to the VPN server must trust the certificate, and the DNS name used to access VPN should be the same common name that is on the certificate.

You need to copy the cert file to the client machine and import it as a trusted root certificate.

This quwalk throughough may help: http://artisticcheese.blogspot.com/2009/04/instructions-how-to-enable-sstp-vpn-s.html

Comment: I got all of that to work, but I'm having a problem now where I'm getting error code "0x800704D4". I went to the URL listed for that item (https://VPN_BOX/sra_%7BBA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75%7D/), and I get a 503 Service Unavailable error. What now?

Comment: try a new question with nore details about what you've done so far with a simiar title to this one to restart the discussion.  also indicate where you get that error and how you are connecting (client vpn setup, etc.)

Comment: If my answer helped you create a self signed cert and resolve the specific error you had in the origional question please mark it so, thanks.